# Error Running Windows Filtering Platform Sample

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, wfp

I am trying to test WFP(Windows Filtering Platform) sample provided by microsoft. While testing I got error.

While building it builds well: With following message:

> Build started: Project: package (Package\package), Configuration: Win8 Debug Win32 ------
>   Inf2Cat task was skipped as there were no inf files to process
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

And While running the exe file I got an error. as:

> "Cannot Verify Digital signature of the file.......".

how to resolve this.

Code From: [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-27553baa#content)

I am using Windows 8 Release Preview machine with Visual studio 2012.